# boolean variable flipping on itself

Tags: c#

I'm doing..

```
item.IsEnabled = !item.IsEnabled;
```

Is there a less verbose way e.g.

```
someInteger++;
```

**Imagine:**

```
thisIsAnExceptionallyLongNamedVariable.IsSomeBooleanValue = !thisIsAnExceptionallyLongNamedVariable.IsSomeBooleanValue
```

Comment: No there isn't. That said - can you provide more context?

Comment: Just why would you do that?

Comment: If I read `IsEnabled` I would asume that this is a read-only property anyway - why would I **set** `IsEnabled` or *switch* it from outside?

Comment: What ?  you want increment operator which is equivalent to comparison operator  ?

Comment: @Vivekh no he wants something to switch a boolean property/field using a operator similar to the increment operator. Something like `myObject.MyBooleanProperty.Switch()` - but using an opertor ;)

Comment: None of the unary operators have compound-assignment versions.  And yeah, I'm sad about that too.

Comment: Fair points given on my answer - I just thought it read nicer than negating as the OP has or XOR'ing as Jacob shows.

Comment: BTW, in C++ `++` does work on `bool` variables, but it just sets the value to `true`, doesn't toggle it.

Comment: `item.IsEnabled ^= true` is shorter -- it's not readable, though.

Answer (score 2):

```
item.IsEnabled ^= true;
```

(`^=` is the exclusive or (XOR) operator.  Since `true^true==false` and `false^true==true`, the above has the effect of inversion.)

Answer (score 2):

The only way to flip the boolean value *while using the variable name only once* is (as Jacob Krall showed):

```
 myBool ^= true; // flip the value
```

Whether that is readable or not is arguable, but most people seem to think it is *not*. (Readability might be improved slightly with a small comment like above.)

Other variants include:

```
myBool = !myBool; // preferred, in my opinion
```

and

```
myBool = myBool == false;
```

---

*A side note regarding multi-threading:* It might be worth noting that, in case of a property access like `a.B`, only `^= true` would be immune to multi-threading issues where the value of `a` might change in the middle of the assignment (however unlikely that is).

Looking at the generated IL, the only difference between the above versions is, the compiler loads the value of `a` twice in the latter two versions. However, the former only loads it once and then duplicates the value onto the evaluation stack. Therefore, it is *guaranteed* to set the property value onto the same object it read the value from. On the other hand, others could possibly read the value from one object and set the flipped value onto another object (under these unlikely scenarios).